# How to share variables with siblings?

Tags: html, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm very new to Polymer, so please don't hold back any information!

I have a basic webpage with a standard format, and I'm trying to figure out how I can expose the `#nav` component variable `currentSelection` with the `#main` component, which depends on the selection for switching out the correct template:

```
head
body
    div#nav
    div#main
    div#footer
```

I understand the encapsulation aspect of Polymer, but I lack an understanding of the glue, eventing system, and different instantiation patterns for the dynamic HTML, especially since Polymer 0.5 is deprecated.

Does `<template is="dom-bind">` actually render as if it weren't a `<template>`? I'm thinking to wrap the whole site in one, but I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make your `#nav` and `#main` custom components? That way you could bind to `currentSelection` like so:

```
<my-nav current-selection="{{currentSelection}}"></my-nav>
<my-main current-selection="[[currentSelection]]"></my-main>
```

The `dom-bind` template is necessary to make bindings work between elements in the main document (i.e index.html), so you could either use `dom-bind`:

```
<template is="dom-bind"> 
    <my-nav current-selection="{{currentSelection}}"></my-nav>
    <my-main current-selection="[[currentSelection]]"></my-main>
    <my-footer></my-footer>
</template>
```

Or you could put all of your elements in another custom component such as `my-app` in which the bindings will work:

#### index.html

```
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

#### my-app.html

```
<template>
    <my-nav current-selection="{{currentSelection}}"></my-nav>
    <my-main current-selection="[[currentSelection]]"></my-main>
    <my-footer></my-footer>
</template>
```

Comment: thank you, this is definitely going in the right direction